# Use vue-cli-service to build a library, how to transpile?

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, vue-cli-3

I'm trying to build a library (mostly some .vue components) to reuse in different projects (no public npm) with vue-cli-service. Apparently everything its already setup, and I can confirm that the build is fine (js, and css). However, I'm unable to use it in a separate project as an external module because it uses the spread operator (and probably more ES20XX features no yet parsed).

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2683:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     params() {
|       const queryParams = {
|         ...this.filters,
|         ...this.sorting,
|         ...this.config.params,
```

This is the standard command I'm using to build the library

`vue-cli-service build --target lib --name [mylibname] ./src/components/index.js`

By default the bundle should be already [polyfilled](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#polyfills-when-building-as-library-or-web-components) but it seems to me that it's not the case.

I've read that I might change the webpack configuration on the project I'm using into, but I'm against parsing the whole `node_module` folder and also I would love to just have the simplest workflow possible (like import a module and its css).

So my question is, how to polyfill my bundle to be perfectly usable in no matter what Vue project without any hassle ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that reinitializing the project with vue-cli without typescript and with separated configuration files instead of into package.json was a good idea, as now is transpiled as needed.

```
var queryParams = _objectSpread({}, this.filters, {}, this.sorting, {}, this.config.params);
```

Unfortunately the hidden configuration of vue-cli webpack can't help to see what has changed.